# createsample.exe crashes every time

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, createsamples

Hi I am trying to create samples using opencv_createsamples.exe but it crashes every time. I've checked different builds, opencv2 and opencv3. I don't know how to overcome this. My command looks like this

```
opencv_createsamples.exe -img C:/Users/dpach/Pictures/Interfejsy/img/1.jpg -maxxangle 15 -maxyangle 15 -maxzangle 1 -w 80 -h 40 -vec test.vec -bgtresh 0 -bgcolor 0 -show
```

The windows to show samples is opening but after that I receive info that program is not responding. Any ideas ?

// EDIT
I've tried to start it from a pseudo unix bash and I receive then `Segmentation fault`

// EDIT2
It crush after that `Create training samples from single image applying distortions...`

Comment: angles must be given in radians. try 15/180*pi = 0.261799387799 instead. read http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html